# Python logging string not being formatter

Tags: python, logging, formatting, string-formatting

I'm trying to use python logging creating one logger per class.

**The essential problem is that my output if not being formatted at all, it justs prints out the format string.**

This is the script I'm usign to create the logger:

```
def obtener_logger_experimental(nombre, file=None, root=False, format=None, level=logging.DEBUG):
    if not isinstance(nombre, str):
        raise TypeError("El nombre del logger debe de ser un string")
    if format is None:
        # format = '%(levelname)s: %(asctime)-15s %(name)s\t%(message)s'
        # format = '%(asctime)-15s %(message)s'
        format = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(funcName)2s()]\t%(message)s"
    else:
        if not isinstance(format, str):
            raise TypeError("El format del logger debe de ser un string")
    formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=format)
    logging.basicConfig(level=level, format=format)
    if root:
        logger = logging.getLogger(nombre)
    else:
        logger = logging.Logger(name=nombre, level=level)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    handler_root = False
    if root:
        if hasattr(logger, 'root'):
            if hasattr(logger.root, 'handlers'):
                for handler in logger.root.handlers:
                    # Ñapa, pero funciona.
                    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
                    handler.setLevel(level)
                    handler_root = True
    else:
        # No sé si esto funciona.
        logger.propagate = False
    if file is not None:
        try:
            if not verificar_permiso_escritura(fichero=file, soloficheros=True):
                raise FileExistsError("El fichero de log no existe o no hay permisos para crearlo / editarlo: " + file)
        except Exception as e:
            raise FileExistsError("Error verificando los permisos del fichero " + file + " Excepcion: " + str(e))
        handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename=file, when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=30)
        handler.setLevel(level)
        #Error was here
        #handler.setFormatter(fmt=format)
        handler.setFormatter(fmt=formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    else:
        # Si queremos loggear a stdout y no hemos encontrado el handler root (o no lo queremos) crear un handler propio.
        if not handler_root:
            handler = logging.StreamHandler()
            handler.setLevel(level)
            # Error was here
            # handler.setFormatter(fmt=format)
            handler.setFormatter(fmt=formatter)
            logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

However, it doesn't matter which way the scripts follows (root, custom StreamHandler or Filehandler), no matter which log I try to output, this is the output I get in console/file:

```
%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(name)s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d - %(funcName)2s()]    %(message)s
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a typo.

```
handler.setFormatter(fmt=format)
```

shoul've been:

```
handler.setFormatter(fmt=formatter)
```

Comment: I was just gonna answer that - rows 40 and 47 had a mistake. I recommend starting with a smaller function, confirming that it works properly and only then adding bells and whistles that raise exceptions in case the user is not being nice. Inak je jednoduchsie ak si to pises po anglicky lebo potom to netreba lustit po tebe.

Comment: Thats what I did, and it worked, but in some point I introduced the typo xD. I think somewhere "formatter" was called "format" and I changed it without IDE's refractor to make more semantically precise, and when I renamed the format string to "format" it made it sintactically correct.